# React Navigation: Back buttons are not showing for stack navigator screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I created a stack navigator and the headers show up properly except for the back button for all the screens inside the navigator. The weird thing is that when I click on where the back button is supposed to be, it works.

The intention is to show the 'back' icon without the back button title, but the icon is not visible.

Any idea on what might went wrong? Is this a known issue in react navigation? Here is the part of the code, very simple:

```
 /*
 */

 function LoginStackScreen() {
   return (
     <LoginStack.Navigator>
       <LoginStack.Screen
         name="Login"
         component={Login}
         options={{ title: null }}
       />
     </LoginStack.Navigator>
   );
 }

 function MainStackScreen() {
   return (
     <MainStack.Navigator>
       <MainStack.Screen
         name="HomeTab"
         component={HomeTab}
         options={{ headerShown: false }}
       />
       <MainStack.Screen
         name="Post"
         component={Post}
         options={{
           headerBackTitleVisible: false,
           headerTitle: null,
           headerTintColor: "black",
           headerStyle: { shadowColor: "transparent" },
         }}
       />
       <MainStack.Screen
         name="Profile"
         component={Profile}
         options={({ route }) => ({
           headerBackTitleVisible: false,
           headerTintColor: "black",
           headerStyle: { shadowColor: "transparent" },
         })}
       />
       <MainStack.Screen
         name="Mypage"
         component={Mypage}
         options={{
           headerBackTitleVisible: false,
           headerTitle: null,
           headerTintColor: "black",
           headerStyle: { shadowColor: "transparent" },
         }}
       />
     </MainStack.Navigator>
   );
 }

 export default function App() {
   /*

     */
   return (
     <NavigationContainer>
       <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
         {user.data === null ? <LoginStackScreen /> : <MainStackScreen />}
       </SafeAreaView>
     </NavigationContainer>
   );
 }
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

in the MainStack.screen you have a option named headerBackTitleVisible : false, if you changhe this value to true or erase this option you can show the back button

```
<MainStack.Screen
     name="Post"
     component={Post}
     options={{
       headerBackTitleVisible: false,  // this
       headerTitle: null,
       headerTintColor: "black",
       headerStyle: { shadowColor: "transparent" },
     }}
   />
```

EDIT:

I have tried this in a project and it shows me the back icon but not the title Greetings!

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="Name"
    component={Component}
    options={{
      headerTitle: null,
      headerTintColor: "black",
      headerStyle: { shadowColor: "transparent" },
    }}
  />
```

Comment: Hi Enzo, my intention is actually hide the title but show the back icon itself, so I set headerBackTitleVisible to false intentionally. Any idea on how to show the icon? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this still concerns anyone, this was a known issue in RN0.62. This was fixed in later versions, but here is the temporary fix that worked for me:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29237#issuecomment-698179801

Answer (score -1):

`headerBackTitleVisible` will hide both title and icon .

you can set `headerBackTitle` to "" to hide title only

```
<MainStack.Screen
     name="Post"
     component={Post}
     options={{
       headerBackTitleVisible: true,  // this
       headerBackTitle : "",  // add this
       headerTitle: null,
       headerTintColor: "black",
       headerStyle: { shadowColor: "transparent" },
     }}
   />
```